# Line Integral : Work done moving along a certain path

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the work done by the force field $F(x,y) = -xi + 6yj$ along the path $C:y = x^3$ from $(0,0)$ to $(6,216)$

I tried parameterizing C which gave me $x(t) = t$ and $y(t) = t^3$ but do I use those two to find $ds$ or do I use the original function $F(x,y)$?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possibly by definition $\displaystyle \int _CF\mid \mathrm d \vec r=\int \limits _a^b\left \langle F(\gamma (t)),\gamma'(t)\right\rangle\mathrm dt$, where $\gamma \colon [a,b]\to \mathbb R^2$ is a parametrization of $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the definition of a Line Integral for Vector Fields ($\mathrm ds$ is for integrals with respect to arc length).

HINT: In plain words, denote and evaluate $F$ at $\alpha$ (substitute, take the dot product and integrate!)

SPOILER!

> $W=\displaystyle\int_0^6[-t,6t^3]\cdot[1,3t^2]\,\mathrm dt$
> $\alpha:(0,6)\rightarrow C\in\mathbb{R}^2,\,t\mapsto[t,t^3]$

Comment: Thank you! Following your hint, I ended up with $int_0^6[-1/2t+18t^5 dt]$ which gave me 13,9950 when evaluated. That seems like a very large value for the work done. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Do not worry, it is right, for the vector field given and the curve you are taking.

Answer (score 0):

$dr=x(t) \hat{\imath}+y(t) \hat{\jmath}$

$$\text{ Work }=\int_C F \cdot dr=\int_0^6 F(t) \cdot \frac{dr}{dt}dt= \int_0^6 (-t \hat{\imath}+6t^3 \hat{\jmath}) \cdot (\hat{\imath}+3t^2 \hat{\jmath})dt=\int_0^6 (-t+18t^5)dt=\left [-\frac{t^2}{2}+3t^6 \right ]_0^6$$